# How to make floating text with HTML5 Canvas?

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

```js
var s = document.getElementById("flame-canvas");
var c = canvas.getContext("2d");
var i = document.createElement("img");
i.src = "http://lj.x10.bz/flame.png";
c.drawImage(i, 0, 0);
```

```html
<canvas id="flame-canvas" width="200" height="200">Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
```

I want to make [this canvas](https://jsfiddle.net/LJNeon/gL2k3g7q/1/) generate a floating text effect created by the canvas at a random spot on the canvas whenever a function is called.  How would I do this?  (Using `requestAnimationFrame()` if possible)

[Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/LJNeon/699g0g4x/) an example of the kind of effect I'd like to create, with the same amount of customization as well.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Your question is too broad to be a good question on Stackoverflow (it has too many variations of answers). To give you a start: 1. Create an object representing each floating letter (`{letter:'A',x:50,y:100, opacity:1.00}`) and save all the objects in an array. 2. Create a requestAnimation loop that reduces the y-value of each object and reduces its opacity if less than a specified y. 3. Clear the canvas and redraw all objects in their new positions & opacities. Come back to SO if you have questions relating to specific code. :-)

Comment: Thanks, [here's](https://jsfiddle.net/LJNeon/Lobjb4w6/1/) what I did.

Comment: instead of saying 'here is what I did' as a comment, include that information as part of your question above